# With my script is sending Error: connect ETIMEDOUT?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an error when I try to make a connection with my BD. It's working but it appears to be losing the connection after a few seconds.

I added some parameters fallowing similar subject on google like path port .... I also changed the port from 8080 to 8081 and its still not working.

I've started with nodeJS 2 days and need some advise.

Could you check my code ?

Thanks in advance

[image]

```
const express = require('express');
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    app = express(), 
    port = 8081, 
    connect = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "api_school",
        path: "http://localhost:8081",
        port: 8081
    });

connect.connect();


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.ejs')
});


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 8081!`));
```

new config :

```
const express = require('express');
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    app = express(), 
    port = 8080, 
    connect = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "api_school",
        port: 3306
    });

connect.connect();
```

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: And are you running your app **and** your db on the same port?? In general, are you sure MySQL is listening on port 8081?

Comment: I usually start the app with node command. How can I check that ?

Comment: You have configured both mysql and your app to listen at same port. You should change the mysql port usually 3306 or the port where mysql is listening.

Comment: @Candy I think it's more likely that MySql is listening on the correct port and OP is just confused about what they should put in the `port` configuration field for the db connection.

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing because your app couldn't connect to your MySQL database within given time hence throwing `ETIMEDOUT`.
It can't be that your node server port and MySQL port same. Also `path` is not required. You need to change the `port` of MySQL configuration to correct one. (Default MySQL post is `3306`).
The `createConnection` config will look like this with default parameters-

```
connect = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "api_school",
        port: 3306
    });
```

Comment: I've change with the configuration and still have the error.

Comment: What did you change? What port is mysql running on? Help us help you.

Comment: @KimCorhvan Please find out on which port MySQL is running from config file and also confirm that MySQL service is active.

Comment: check if you can connect to MySQL from the terminal with the credentials provided in `mysql.createConnection`. Also please check if MySQL is running or not.

Comment: now check `user`, `password` is correct and also check if table `api_school` exits. Make sure you can login to MySQL using the `user` name and `password`

Comment: @UsamaTahir, MySQL port is 3306 and Mamp is activated

Comment: are you using exactly this object for connection?
```
{
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "api_school",
        port: 3306
    }
```

Comment: @UsamaTahir  yes it is

Comment: @KimCorhvan I will need to look at the code. can you please the repo link? I can debug the issue.